# Schengen Visa - Tourist visa (visiting friends) or Tourist visa (simple)

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-accommodation

My friend is a student in Germany who is on a student visa. I want to surprise him on his birthday by turning up at his house on the day. When I apply for a visa, should I apply for a Tourist visa (Visiting friends or relatives) or should I apply for a Tourist travel (no visit to any relatives/friends)? I don't want to get any invitation documentations from my friend since it wouldn't be a surprise then. I will be sponsoring the entire trip myself

Comment: It's not a big difference if you are self-sufficient; overall, disclosure is the best policy.  If you are visiting friends, then you can apply that way.

Comment: But wouldn't hat require an invitation letter from my friend?

Comment: Are you relying upon your friend for accommodation or maintenance support? Then yes.

Comment: No. I will be sponsoring the entire trip including what is required for accommodation and other expenses. But I might stay stay at my friend's also.

Comment: That's fine.  Original comment applies.

Comment: By “friend” do you mean someone with whom you are romantically involved?

Comment: May be I hope to be.

Answer (score 1):

A Schengen visa is a Schengen visa, there are no strictly defined categories. If you want to rely on your friend's financial support or accommodation then you will indeed need a formal invitation. Otherwise, just be upfront and truthful and it should be fine. If you are unsure about which box to check, just choose “other” and write a short explanation.